# While I create Event Subscription for Storage Account, 'create' button is grayed out

Tags: azure

I can not create Event Subscription in Azure portal for Storage Account

I researched and found some recommendations that I should try it on Microsoft Edge.
But It did not help me.
I also registered Microsoft.EventGrid in Resource providers of My Subscription. No positive progress

Answer (score 0):

***I tried the same in my environment in both Edge and Chrome and I was facing the same issue.***

[image]

- **This seems to be a bug in Azure.**

***To achieve the same, I tried below:***

- Search for `Event Subscriptions` under Home in Portal.
- Click on `+Event Subscription/ Create One` to create new subscription.

[image]

- Configure your `Storage account` in `Topic Details` and `Event Hub` in `Endpoint Type`, Click `Create`:

[image]

- Once the `Subscription` gets created, Navigate to your `Storage Account=>Events=>Event Subscriptions` you'll be able to see the newly created subscription.

[image]

**References:**

[Azure Portal won't let me create a subscription to an Azure event grid topic. Create button greyed out - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66481745/azure-portal-wont-let-me-create-a-subscription-to-an-azure-event-grid-topic-cr)